# How to filter based on multiple field value in elastic search java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, playframework

I have tried to setup a post filter for multiple field in elastic search. But it not working. Please tell me how to setup ?

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("idx_articles").setTypes("articles")
                .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("pubish", true))
                .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status", "active"))
                .setQuery(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("title", "pub"+"*"))
                .addSort("articleVersion", SortOrder.DESC) // Filter
                .execute().actionGet();
```

it only considering .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("status", "active"))

it not considering the filter .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("pubish", true))

Pls tell me hoow to setup multiple field filter?

Answer (score -1):

U can Use Bool filter Inside Post filter like below

```
setPostFilter(FilterBuilders.boolFilter()
                .must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("pubish", true))
                .must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("status", "active")))
```

For Reference

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.3/bool-filter.html